# How can i get source info from customer object when create a customer in stripe using asp.net core?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

```
var customerService = new CustomerService();
Customer customer = customerService.Get(session.CustomerId);
```

this customer > **source** return **null**. When create a stripe checkout payment then create this customer but **card** info like ******4242** but this info I can't retrieve. Is it possible?

I want source info like **tok_visa**, **tok_mastercard** etc.

I try to charge a saved customer and who had already paid. Because if he select **monthly** payment then I want to charge it my system using **background job**. Is it possible?

```
var option1 = new ChargeCreateOptions
                {
                    Customer = customerId,
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "usd",
                    Source = "", //here i can use this source info
                    Description = "",
                };
                var service1 = new ChargeService();
                var test = service1.Create(option1);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are trying to get the source from a Customer, but how did you attach the source? If you haven't, there is no source to retrieve.

If you used Stripe Checkout then you want to look at its attached Payment Method instead by Listing Payment Methods on a Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list

Comment: When redirect checkout after payment does not the source automatically be attached?
if not, When I am using **SessionCreateOptions** in payment. How can I attach this object for **customer >source**? @orakaro

Comment: When a customer first pays, save the customer ID and the source ID to your database.Set up a background job that runs monthly.When the job runs, it retrieves the customer ID and source ID from your database.Use those IDs to create a new charge.In your code snippet, you should assign the saved source ID to the `Source` property of the `ChargeCreateOptions` object. If you're using the default source, you don't need to set it explicitly; Stripe will use the default source associated with the customer.

Comment: But @JalpaPanchal, In my case, When customer first pays then I found source is null. So, How can I get this **source**?

Comment: it could be due to the newer API versions where Stripe has transitioned from using the `source` to using `PaymentMethod` objects for handling card details.you could use the Payment Intents API for handling payments.When a customer makes a payment, you should save their payment method for future use. You can do this by setting the `setup_future_usage` property when creating the payment intent. Once a payment method has been saved to a customer, you can retrieve it by listing all payment methods attached to the customer or tracking payment method ID when you first create the payment intent.

Comment: If you are using CheckoutSession then no, no Source will be generated. Source is a legacy API, while Checkout is newer and goes with Payment Method API (a replacement of Source). You can find out which Payment Method (pm_xxx) has been used and set it into PaymentIntent: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method

Answer (score 0):

**Part one - the history of Stripe payment method tokens**
There are two payment method Tokens to speak of: Sources and Payment Methods.

-Sources are the old type of payment method Token (I'm sure somebody will feel obliged to point out that 'old' and 'deprecated' are not the same, but that's pedantic, Sources have been deprecated for over 6 years).

ID structure for Sources vary depending on the payment method type and Token type:
-Tokens (tok_xxx)
-Card Sources (card_xxx)
-Sources (src_xxx)
-Bank Accounts (ba_xxx)
-Bank Account Tokens (btok_xxx)

-Payment Methods are the new way to tokenize payment methods. They have one ID structure across all payment method types: pm_xxx.

Any* new hosted process like Checkout and Payment Links will create Payment Methods.
Any custom process integrated by users *should* use Payment Methods.

*I believe the hosted Invoice payment page still tokenizes card payment methods as card sources (card_xxx).

**Part two - How to find any of these Tokens on Customers**
You won't see any Token on your Customer unless the payment method is set as default for them. This is important, because Checkout doesn't set payment method as default, by default.

If the Customer has a default Source, you'll find it in their `default_source` attribute.
If they have a default Payment Method, you'll find it in their `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` attribute.

If your Customer has an attached card which isn't set as default, you can only find it by listing it. I would strongly recommend [listing Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list) in any use-case, since it returns both Sources and Payment Methods (though it will list Payment Methods first).

Finally if your Customer doesn't have an attached card, meaning you didn't save the card for future use during their payment, then you can't find it with either way given above. You can only really get it by [retrieving the Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve) that used it.

Comment: "You won't see any Token on your Customer unless the payment method is set as default for them." That's actually not true of Sources, judging my this. Still, no equivalent to this for Payment Methods. https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-sources